# Google App Engine Java Deployment and Servlet/jsp relationship

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I am trying to understand application deployment on Google App Engine using java. Looks like  if java is used it is more like deployment of a web application which extends java servlet ( HttpServlet ). Let me know if java application can be deployed without using servlet or jsp.

I agree in addition to standard web application deployment it will require GAE specific configuration i.e. appengine-web.xml. But my question is mainly on requirement of servlet for java based deployment.

Sorry for very basic question, but all code samples pointed me to servlet but in document there is   no mention about servlet.

Comment: what kind of application you want to deploy then?

Comment: I mostly will be developing Android Applications which require some servers side scripting. But regardless of kind of application, am curious to understand does GAE always dependent on Servelt or JSP whether directly or indirectly.  As per below answer from 3371862, I recon servlet/jsp does require, though it is auto generated through by end-point framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand you want to communicate with the server via HTTP. *Servlets* are most common way to support this protocol in JVM, unless you want to implement protocol in something low level, like in Netty.

Servlet is a set of java interfaces, but it is not required to implement them by yourself. Most Java web frameworks provide some implementation for you. I mean someone should write this servlet once, but most likely it was written by frameworks authors many years ago, you don't even need to think about its implementation.

For example I don't remember writing any Servlet since 2003, but I have plenty of working web apps on GAE. Most of them are Spring based, it have Spring Dispatcher Servlet which does all processing HTTP request/response for you.

So the answer is: yes App Engine is Servlet based app container and you need one, but it's very unlikely you'll write any servlet by yourself

Comment: Thanks, it make sense.. can you please let me have name of commonly used best frameworks google and non googles

Comment: For GAE _Google Endpoints_ is recommended, especially if you're writing a backed for Android app. For general webapps I recommend Spring MVC, as most flexible framework

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which tools (frameworks) you are using in App Engine you may OR NOT write Servlets and JSPs. For example if you use Google Endpoints (https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/java/about-cloud-endpoints-frameworks), you will not write any servlet yourself: they will be automatically generated by the framework itself.

On the other hand it is totally possible to deploy your own servlets and JSPs, and adapt the web.xml file accordingly.

Comment: ok, does that mean it eventually require servlet and JSP,  however end point frame work can write them for us ?

Comment: Java Google Cloud Endpoints (running on App Engine) "requires" servlets (not JSPs) but it is transparent for you: as said above the servlets are automatically generated. The other great advantage for Android (referring to your comment above, where you mention that you're building an Android app) is that it also automatically generates the client libraries components for Android that will greatly accelerate the work on the Android side.